# Netsuite webservices: search transactions by vendor internal id

Tags: xml, web-services, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to search for transactions (vendor bills specifically) in NetSuite webservices 2017_2 within a certain time period for a specified vendor, identified by `internalId`. However, it seems that the vendor's `internalId` part does not work for me. Omitting it I can get many transactions back.

Can someone help me solve the `vendorJoin` part or propose a different filter to get only one vendor's transactions in a certain time window?

```
<Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <search xmlns="urn:sales_2017_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <searchRecord xsi:type="tranSales:TransactionSearch">
            <tranSales:basic>
                <tranDate xmlns="urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" operator="within">
                    <searchValue xmlns="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xsi:type="" type="" internalId="">2019-02-01T00:00:00+02:00</searchValue>
                    <searchValue2 xmlns="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xsi:type="" type="" internalId="">2019-04-01T00:00:00+04:00</searchValue2>
                </tranDate>
                <type xmlns="urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xsi:type="platformCore:SearchEnumMultiSelectField" operator="anyOf">
                    <searchValue xmlns="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xsi:type="xsd:string" type="" internalId="">vendorBill</searchValue>
                </type>
            </tranSales:basic>
            <vendorJoin xmlns="urn:sales_2017_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <internalId xmlns="urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" operator="anyOf" xsi:type="platformCore:SearchMultiSelectField">
                    <searchValue xmlns="urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef" type="vendor" internalId="125554"></searchValue>
                </internalId>
            </vendorJoin>
        </searchRecord>
    </search>
</Body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the SOAP Body above works just fine I had some other unrelated bug in the code and a lot of data that made me think the query is not working.